# Ext JS VBox shrink bottom container before top container

Tags: javascript, extjs, vbox

I have an Ext JS Panel with a layout of VBox (align stretch). In it, there are two containers.

When the window resizes, I want the containers to resize like this:

[image: desired resize functionality]

*Note: the top section needs to have a minimum height of `200px`. The content on each of the elements should overflow automatically.*

**EDIT:** To clarify, each image shows the desired layout of the panel at various window sizes. Here is an explanation of each image (left to right):

1. The layout when all of the content fits into the window. The top section's height is determined (in this state) by the height of its child elements.
2. The layout when the window has been resized vertically to a point where the bottom section is `100px` tall (the max height). **Up until this point, the bottom section will resize and overflow, but the top section's height will stay the same.**
3. The layout when the window has been resized even more. Now, **instead of the bottom section resizing, the top section should resize and overflow.**

Here is my code (simplified for readability):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch',
    },
    autoScroll: true,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            autoScroll: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },

            minHeight: 200

            items: [
                // There are a few variable height elements here
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'bottomSection',
            minHeight: 100,
            autoScroll: true
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
});
```

This works to some extent, but after the bottom section has resized to the minimum height (`100px`), the top section does not begin shrink.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality using pure Ext JS? If there isn't, is there a simple way to do this by handling an event (i.e. `onResize`)?

Comment: I don't really understand picture 2 -> picture 3, if the top part has the size determined by the content, how does it shrink? According to what?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli please see my latest edit. Is there any other information that would be helpful to you?

Comment: No way to do it automatically. You're basically wanting the behaviour to change from measure to flex as things get smaller. You'd need to handle it manually.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Thank you for your time! I was suspecting that was the case, but I was hoping that I might have overlooked something.